# Holding weak reference to ios controller in cpp class

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a c++ class in mm file. The class received a pointer to a controller and holds a reference to it. It seams that the cpp class holds a strong reference to the controller and it causing memory issues.

How can i store a weak reference to the controller?

Comment: have you tried to add __weak modifier?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ARC for individual files in XCode under the 'Build Phases' tab in the build target's properties. Fold out the 'Compile Sources' section and add `-fno-objc-arc` to the compiler flags. In lots of tutorials it is recommended to disable ARC in cpp-classes.

Now, all of your NSObjects in that class will need manual memory management (with calling `retain`/`release` methods).

Answer (score 0):

A mm file is an objective-c++ file, and any classes have the same memory management issues an objective-c objects, except for c++ objects. Thus, if the leaked object in your question is not a c++ object, make it 'weak'. If the object is c++ then you will obviously need a different strategy.